# PHP Magic methods

Tags: php, magic-methods

My question revolves arround magic methods.

This is a little example:

```
$context = new Context('Entities.xml');
$user_array = $context->Users;
$user = $context->Users->find(array('name' => 'John Smith'));
```

The second line returns an array with all user objects in it. The third line returns only the User object of the user called John Smith.

I wondered if this would be possible, the tricky part is that I don't know the properties of the `Context class`. They are generated from an xml file the user supplies upon instantiation and are accessable through magic getters and setters.

`Context` example(not complete, just to give an idea):

```
class Context {
   private $path, $entities;

   public function __construct($path) {
      $this->path = $path;
   }

   public function __get($name) {
      return $entities[$name];
   }

   public function __set($name, $arg) {
      $entities[$name] = $arg;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I really needed a solution I implemented the following solution.

The getters of the `Context` class return a `ResultLayer` class that handles the results.

Example:

```
class ResultLayer implements IteratorAggregate {
    public $data = array();
    private $entity, $context;

    public function __construct($context, $entity) {
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->entity = $entity;
    }

    public function getIterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->data);
    }

    public function get($index) {
        return $this->data[$index];
    }

    public function toArray() {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function find($properties) {
        return $this->context->getEntity($this->entity, $properties);
    }
}
```

I have implemented the `IteratorAggregate` interface so that you can use a `foreach` loop to for example go through `$Context->Users` this makes the code more readable.

If anyone has a better approach, I'm still open to it. Any help is much appreciated!